# How to implement in JEditorPane on text changed

Tags: java, jeditorpane, javax.swing.text

How to implement in JEditorPane on text changed method ( get text on every character added or deleted ) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register a document listener with the document of the JEditorPane which will be notified when text is inserted or removed or when the text style changes.

Take a look at [Java Tutorial > How to Write a Document Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information  about document listeners and document events.